# GtkTextBuffer error when calling buffer.insert_with_tags_by_name invisible

Tags: python, gtk

I'm trying to insert text before and after selection in textbuffer. All works fine but after applying tag program crash with error:

here is part of my code I use:

```
self.tag_bold = self.des_buffer.create_tag("bold", weight=Pango.Weight.BOLD)
self.tag_hide = self.des_buffer.create_tag("hide", invisible=True)

def text_edit(self, widget, html_format_start):
    bounds = self.des_buffer.get_selection_bounds()
    start, end = bounds
    self.des_buffer.insert_with_tags_by_name(start, html_format_start, 'hide')

def on_button_text_bold_clicked(self, widget):
    self.test1 = "<B>"
    self.test2 = "</B>"
    self.text_edit(self, self.tag_hide)
    self.text_edit(self, self.test1)
    self.text_edit(self, self.test2)
```

Error message:

```
(magic-ebay:6056): Gtk-WARNING **: /build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.4.2/./gtk/gtktextbtree.c:4019: byte index off the end of the line
(magic-ebay:6056): Gtk-ERROR **: Byte index 24 is off the end of the line
```

when I only use different tag then hide (invisible) all works fine, no crash occur.
Any idea ?

Comment: You're calling `text_edit()` with the `html_format_start` parameter first being a text tag and then twice being a string?